# SFML:Problem with displaying 2 Rectangles

Tags: c++, sfml

I want create light blue background so I draw 2 rectangles (blue and white).
But when I execute program i see only black screen.Also my video adapter is fully loaded.
Code:

```
int main() {
srand(time(NULL));
RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(500, 500), "Fish!",sf::Style::Close|sf::Style::Resize);
RectangleShape water(Vector2f(500,500));
RectangleShape background(Vector2f(500,500));
background.setFillColor(Color(255,255,255,3));
water.setFillColor(Color(5,45,255,1));
while (window.isOpen()) {
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        switch (event.type) {
            case (sf::Event::Resized):
                break;
            case (sf::Event::Closed):
                window.close();
                break;
        }

    }
    window.clear();
    window.draw(background);
    window.draw(water);
    window.display();

}
```

I need window.clear function because i want insert some object later on the screen!

Comment: Could it be that your alpha values for the rectangles are not high enough? 1 and 3 are pretty low. Have you tried setting them to 255, just to make sure the rectangles are visible at all?

Comment: Yes it helps!! I chose this values without considering using it in cycle!